# HNetCfg.NATUPnP with multiple network cards

Tags: windows, delphi, networking

I am using the following code to look for Forwarded ports...

```
Nat := CreateOleObject('HNetCfg.NATUPnP');
Ports := Nat.StaticPortMappingCollection;

if not VarIsClear ( Ports ) then
begin
  Enum := Ports._NewEnum;
  foreach := enum as IEnumVariant;

  while foreach.Next(1, Port, PDWORD(0)^) = 0 do
  begin
    Desc := Port.Description;       //str
    Enabled := Port.Enabled;        //bool
    ExtIP := Port.ExternalIPAddress;//str
    ExtPort := Port.ExternalPort;   //int
    IntClient := Port.InternalClient; //str
    IntPort := Port.InternalPort;     //int
    Protocol := Port.Protocol;        //str
    temp := Desc + #9;
    if enabled then
      temp := temp + 'True' + #9
    else
      temp := temp + 'False' + #9;
    temp := temp + ExtIP + #9 + IntToStr(ExtPort) + #9 +
      IntClient + #9 + IntToStr(intPort) + #9 + Protocol + #13;
  end;
end;
```

When I run it on my development machine all goes well... I see the data on the router... However, my development machine only has one network card... I have determined that in the production machine (which has 4 adapters... 2 physical and 2 virtual) StaticPortMappingCollection is always null... How do I use this functionality and bind it to a specific card?

Thank you in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HNetCfg.NATUPnP` does not support the functionality you are asking for.  You will have to find another uPNP implementation (or write your own) that gives you control over socket bindings.